# I used the MSSQL Copy Databse Wizard to schedule a copy, how do I cancel it?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, job-scheduler

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

I thought the wizard would be a good idea, but further discussion revealed that the backup/restore method of moving the database would be preferable. Now I can't find any mention of the task I created so that I can cancel it. I named it "MoveOut", but a disk search also failed to find it. I also can't find anything mentioned in Task Scheduler.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Scheduled Task is created on the Destination SQL server, not the Source SQL server, even though I ran the Wizard on the Source.

Hope this helps someone else, somewhere, sometime.